# expected type mismatch error

Tags: vb6

I'm expecting a ByRef Argument Type Mismatch at compile time but I'm not getting it. It's compiling without errors and failing at runtime with error 13, "Type mismatch".

It's a fairly simple to reproduce.

```
dim c as Car
Set c = New Car

Sail c
```

...

```
Public Sub Sail(ByRef b As Boat)
    ...
End Sub
```

Car does **not** inherit from Boat

Is there a setting (or plugin perhaps) that will force VB into a strict compilation mode?

**Edit:** it looks like there's no compiler option for this. Does anyone know of an addon that analyses the source for these casting issues during a compile?

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible to set Option Strict True in VB6?

Edit: Apparently it is not possible in VB6 (seems to have been introduced with VB 7.0)

Comment: No, sorry. Option Strict is not possible in VB6. Option Explicit is available but only ensures that you declare your variables, it does not prevent casting problems

Comment: The link you posted was specific to VB.NET

Comment: I noticed that immediately after I posted it, which is why I removed it.