# Why does VB6 not check object types' correspondence at compile time?

Tags: oop, vb6, type-safety

I still have to deal with Visual Basic 6.

I just found out that the correspondence of object types is enforced only at run time. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549357/expected-type-mismatch-error).

---

I was quite shocked to find this out, I always relied on type safety checks for objects.

Does somebody know if there is an architectural reason for this (that makes it at least a complex problem)?

I would understand it if there were polymorphism involved, but when the type of a parameter is a class not implemented by any other I don't see any problem in type-checking at compile-time...?

Answer (score 4):

***History lesson***

**VB versions 1 to 3** were stricter. Type consistency checks were still made at runtime, but it was stricter. If you assigned a string to an integer, you got a runtime error. I don't know why the consistency checks were only made at runtime - at a guess compile-time checks were harder to implement.

**In VB version 4** the language was changed so that (for instance) assigning a string to an integer would not raise an error, but would implicitly convert the string value to an integer. For instance if the string contained `"0"` or `""` it would be converted to `0`. If the string contained, say `"1E40"` you would get an overflow error. Many VB programmers (including, erm, me) hated this change, and called it evil type coercion. E.g. see this [article](http://vb.mvps.org/articles/pt199511.pdf) by guru Karl Peterson.

So the architectural approach was "try to convert types at runtime by guesswork, only raise an error if it's not possible". And this means, the checks **have** to made at runtime. I suppose in principle the compiler could detect cases where an object type is private, and not implemented by any other class, and check that at compile-time, but I guess that was not a priority for the compiler developers. It might even have been confusing for developers to understand why some assignments were checked at runtime and others at compile time.

In VB.Net the default behaviour is the same as VB6, to make it easier to upgrade legacy code. `Option Strict On` is preferred in VB.Net so that the checking is done at compile time. The compile-time checks are useful because they flag up mistakes early.

Comment: Quite interesting answer, thank you.    
But for normal (non-object) types, for ByRef (the default) parameters of routine calls the checks **are** made at compile-time!    
Now that I think about it it is probably mostly by accident, though, as permitting multiple parts of the code to regard a same variable as having different types _might_ be doable, but would be very complex and messy.

Comment: Yes in the end considering the implicit coercion thing and your mention of complete absence of compile-time checking before that (I wasn't aware of it) it is likely that static checking was not really much in the minds of the VB developers.

Comment: By the way, trying in VB 2010 (with Option Strict Off) I **do** get a compiler error, trying something like the code in the question I referred ([expected-type-mismatch-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549357/expected-type-mismatch-error)), maybe it was missing only in the first .Net versions...?

Comment: I will accept your answer in a few days, if a VB team member doesn't stumble upon this question before.    
I was also interested in potential theoretical problems for this thing, but at this point I realize there are probably none.

Comment: By the way, I've run into the VBA specification ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100108024627/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851%28PROT.10%29.aspx)'s the oldest version, 0.9, about VBA 6.5), it's quite amazing, it describes exactly what happens, although not the reasons (see "_5.3.1.11 Procedure Invocation Argument Processing_" and "_5.5 Implicit coercion_"). Yes, VBA is not VB6, but they widely coincide.

Answer (score 2):

Only interfaces are implemented, not classes. VB6 class `Car` implicitly defines interface `_Car` that can be implemented in any external project (DLL) and can be bundled on a coclass with any other interface (incl `_Boat`)

When you `Dim c As Car` it is the interface `_Car` that's used by the compiler, so `c` can hold a reference to the `_Car` interface on any object, not just an instance of the `Car` class. E.g. you can program a coclass `Mix` that implements both `_Car` and `_Boat` interfaces, so `Set c = New Mix` compiles and runs, and so in `Sail c` the QI for `_Boat` interface actually succeeds (think the "cast" succeeds).

Note that this is not upcast nor downcast, as `_Car` and `_Boat` are not bound by any form on inheritance. But this is what COM allows you to achieve through `IUnknown` interface.

In modern languages they decided that you'll always require downcast explicitly in code (otherwise get a compile error), and the same with "side-casts" (as in the contrived car/boat example) as not to shoot yourself in the leg.

Comment: I apologise for the late reply, I at first took a few days to look into what you brought up and later had little time. (1/6)

Comment: You made some very good points.

I don't think I ever realized that the "Mix to Boat" scenario was possible. I understand that it's due to supporting COM, but it seems crazy! But maybe it's just for VB syntax's confusion between classes and interfaces.
So the "As " always refer to interfaces, and objects are never cast to anything, they always keep all their bag of interfaces no matter from what "interface window" (variable/parameter) you're looking them from.
In trying to be smart VB made a big mess, seems to me. (2/6)

Comment: I didn't consider that a linked external component could be implementing one of the project's classes. This can happen only with non-private classes of ActiveX projects though, right? (3/6)

Comment: So, in that case, if it's possible that the object passed will be external I guess all bets are off and you can't hope to determine if it'll be supporting a specific interface, as: 1) it's probably impossible to predict what type of object you will get, and 2) from what I've seen there could be cases where you can't know if an object support an interface until you query for it (but I'm not really a COM expert).
Thus the compiler would have to find out if the object passed can be external; for sure not a trivial task, and likely impossible in some cases. (4/6)

Comment: In the other cases it might be reasonable to only check if any (internal) class supports both the source and the destination interfaces. You would already catch most of errors.

Still it definitely seems not an easy problem, in general. (5/6)

Comment: By the way it might be obvious but it might be worthy to point out that real upcasts (e.g. passing a Cat to a Mix parameter) are not allowed (although still detected only at run time). (6/6)